# Building android app and running it on device installs application in which folder

Tags: java, android, file, installation, directory

I'm building a small Android app and it is coming along nicely.  When I run the app, I do so on a physical device (HTC ONE).  When I run the app, this is the output on the Run/Console

```
Uploading file
    local path: E:\workspace\TestApp\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.giznaj.TestApp
Installing com.giznaj.TestApp
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.giznaj.TestApp"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.giznaj.TestApp
Success
```

When the app is running I open up explorer (showing hidden files) and I cannot for the life of me find this folder/file.

The reason I am looking for the folder, is that I can open a text file that the app is creating.  I want to check the contents as I am having a hard time using the app to open it.

Comment: FYI Android does not allow you to create a file just where the APK is installed. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: Could you clearify your question? what are you looking for? a database? a simple text file? an image? They are stored in different directories (by default). Seeing your code would help.

Comment: 1st question:  Why can't I see the folders (listed above) in explorer?

Comment: How do I show my code now?  It says it is too long.  I'm only trying to display one method

Comment: When you run an app from within the Android Studio, and you choose to run it on a device (like I mentioned in my opening question) where is it installing the app on the device?  It seems you don't have control on where it is.  If I look at the path from the console you would think you can find it, but I can't.  I am even showing hidden files.

Comment: Would all applications be installed in:
\Internal storage\Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the folder in explorer:
PC\HTC One\Internal storage\Android\data\com.giznaj.TestApp